# Spark 2 performance even run is better than odd

Tags: apache-spark

I am using Spark 2.4.3, want to test its performance. I found an interesting fact: same code as below, same env, run in the spark shell, the even number of run (2, 4, 6..) always is faster than the odd number, for example, No. 2 is faster than first one, No. 3 is faster than second run .... Anyone know why ?

This code will generate random integer, assign to two partitions and get a total.

```
val r = scala.util.Random
val input1 = for (i <- 1 to 10000000) yield r.nextInt
val input = sc.parallelize(input1, 2)

val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
input.reduce((x,y) => x+y)
println((System.currentTimeMillis()-start)+"")
```

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by `run`? a whole new spark-shell process or the same query within the same spark-shell process?

Comment: within same spark shell, run same scripts multiple times.

Comment: Have you checked the cache?